# file pattern exists check under a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

In nodejs there is a file.exists. but it wouldn't navigate recursively through a directory. so what would be the best way to check if a file pattern exists under a directory/return the list using nodejs/javascript?
I don't need to read the file..I just need the match of files only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a module like [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for doing this kind of thing.